# Разделить строку на массивы по типу

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть строка `string!double,double!...`
Как её можно разбить на два массива: `string` и `double`?

```
string array[];
string s= "name!13.6756,14.4732! ...";
char[] splitchar = { '!', ',' };
array = pointStr.Split(splitchar);
```

Comment: Входная строка сформирована по какому-то правилу? Опишите его

Comment: Так есть `double.TryParse` если вернулось true - влево, иначе вправо.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "name!13.6756,14.4732! ...";
char[] separator = { '!', ',' };
var array = s.Split(separator);

var numbers = new List<double>();
var strings = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in array)
{
    if (double.TryParse(item, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double result))
    {
        numbers.Add(result);
    }
    else
    {
        strings.Add(item);
    }
}
```